# Are "Speculate" and "Speculum" related?

Tags: etymology

I wonder if any etymology buffs can shed some light into this one. While commonly a speculum is a [medical instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculum_(medical)), I know it has other uses in literature and history. Is *speculate* a verb extending from *speculum*, as in *to peer into as if using a speculum*?

Comment: Given the definition of *speculum*, *[insert bathroom humor].* Also one more pun about *inserting*.

Comment: As you can see from the answer posted below, a search in an etymology dictionary would have provided you (in great part) with the answer. I doubt anybody else will come up with a more complete answer unless you edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the two terms appear to be related. Both *speculum*  and *speculate*  derive from Latin *specere* ( to look at, view):

[Speculum](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Speculum&searchmode=none):

> - 1590s, in surgery and medicine, "instrument for rendering a part accessible to observation," from Latin speculum "reflector, looking-glass, mirror" (also "a copy, an imitation"), **from specere "to look at, view"**  As a type of telescope attachment from 1704.

[Speculate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Speculate&searchmode=none):

> - **1590s, "view mentally, contemplate" (transitive), back-formation from speculation.** Also formerly "view as from a watchtower" (1610s). Intransitive sense of "pursue truth by conjecture or thinking" is from 1670s. *Meaning "to invest money upon risk for the sake of profit" is from 1785.*

[Speculation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Speculation&searchmode=none):

> - *late 14c., "intelligent contemplation, consideration; act of looking," from Old French speculacion "close observation, rapt attention," and directly from Late Latin speculationem (nominative speculatio) "contemplation, observation," noun of action from Latin speculatus, past participle of speculari "observe," **from specere "to look at, view"**.
> - Meaning "pursuit of the truth by means of thinking" is from mid-15c. Disparaging sense of "mere conjecture" is recorded from 1570s. Meaning "buying and selling in search of profit from rise and fall of market value" is recorded from 1774; short form spec is attested from 1794.

Source:http: www.etymonline.com